# ref for variables not parameters in functions

Tags: c#, ref

Suppose I have a `Person` class and have the following:

```
Person A = new Person("Tom");
Person B = A;
```

Is there a way I can change it so that if I assign a new `Person` to `B`, `B = new Person("Harry")`, `A` would be referring to the same instance too?  I know you can do that in a `ref` parameter assignment in a function.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

UPDATE: The feature described here was added to C# 7.

---

The feature you want is called "ref locals" and it is not supported in C#.

The CLR does support generating code that contains ref locals, and a few years ago I wrote an experimental version of C# that had the feature you want, just to see if it would work. You could do something like:

```
Person a = whatever;
ref Person b = ref a;
```

and then as you say, changes to "b" would change the contents of "a". The two variables become aliases for the same storage location.

Though it was a nice little feature and worked well, we decided to not take it for C#. It's possible that it could still happen in a hypothetical future version of the language, but I would not get all excited about it in expectation; it will probably not happen.

(Remember, all of Eric's musings about hypothetical future versions of any Microsoft product are For Entertainment Purposes Only.)

Comment: Is there any use for this? I can't think of any at the moment except if we want to confuse readers...

Comment: @configurator: Some algorithms become easier to write if you can make an alias to a variable and change which variable it refers to. And there are also scenarios where you can increase the speed of certain performance-sensitive code.

Comment: @EricLippert the newest version of c# supports this feature if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Zer0: Thanks for the note; I will update the text.

Answer (score 4):

No it isn't possible in safe code(beyond `ref` function parameters). In unsafe code you might be able to use pointers to achieve that, but I don't think that's a good idea.

`A` contains the reference to "Tom" as a value. You'd need a reference to `A` to change where it points.

If we consider similar code in a language which explicitly uses pointers instead of implicitly treating instances of classes as references:

```
Person* A=new Person("Tom");
Person* B=A;
B=new Person("Harry");//Changes only B
Person** C=&A;
(*C)=new Person("John");//Now A changes
```

So you need a pointer to a pointer in order to change `A`. If you transfer this to C# you'd need a reference to a local variable. And those are only available in the form of `ref` function parameters. This avoids some lifetime issues since a reference to a local variable can't safely outlive that local variable.

If these are not private variables you could make B a property that modifies A in the setter.

```
Person B{get{return A;} set{A=value;}}
```

Comment: Just as a note: C# DOES support pointers VERY similar to your sample. They are just not widely used (as I wrote in my answer).

Comment: Yes C# it does support pointers in some limited contexts. But it doesn't use an explicit notation for references/pointers in this context. If you declare `Person` as a class variables of its type are implicitly treated as a pointer/reference.

Answer (score 2):

There is no direct way to do that.

You can either take a source-code approach like:

```
A = B = new Person("Harry")
```

Or use a generic type. Something like:

```
var A = new ReferenceHolder<Person> (new Person("Tom")); 
var B = A;
```

In C# you could also use a pointer (so basically a ref type) but that approach is not statically verifyable and not suggested.